# Helm task to deploy resource to AKS get connection error

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using Helm to upgrade the AKS resource via Azure DevOps. But when I deploy the helm chart, it show the following error:

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://aks.xxxxxxx.azmk8s.io:443/version": dial tcp 20.255.255.140:443; i/o timeout
```

YAML

```
steps:
...
- task: HelmDeploy@0
  displayName: 'helm upgrade'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: xx
    azureResourceGroup: xx
    kubernetesCluster: xx
    useClusterAdmin: true
    namespace: prod
    command: upgrade
    chartName: 'AKS_Chart_Prod'
    releaseName: 'Prod_release'
    valueFile: myvals.yaml
    force: true
```

We can manually deploy the helm chart on local machine.

How to solve the issue in Azure Pipeline?

Comment: Looks like an issue with your kubectl configuration. You have `httpss://` where it should likely be `https://`

Comment: Sorry. This is what I input incorrectly when hiding the URL information. I have updated the question.

Comment: What kind of agent are you using? Self-hosted agent or Microsoft-hosted agent. You need to confirm if the firewall has been enabled in AKS.

Comment: If you can deploy the helm chart successfully on local machine, you can consider using [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#install).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is a Private AKS cluster. We are using Microsoft-hosted agent. Can we keep using Microsoft-hosted agent to run the helm task? or we need to change to use self-hosted agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the AKS cluster is private, the Helm task can not directly access the AKS cluster when using the Microsoft-Hosted Agent.

To keep using the Microsoft-hosted Agent, you can change to use the Azure CLI to do the helm upgrade operation.

For example:

```
az aks command invoke --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myPrivateCluster --command "helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami && helm repo update && helm install my-release bitnami/nginx"
```

Refer to this doc: [Access a private Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/access-private-cluster?tabs=azure-cli)

> With the Azure CLI, you can use command invoke to access private clusters without the need to configure a VPN or Express Route. command invoke allows you to remotely invoke commands, like kubectl and helm, on your private cluster through the Azure API without directly connecting to the cluster.

Here is the Pipeline example:

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: azure
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'az aks command invoke --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myPrivateCluster --command "helm upgrade --namespace xx --install --values /test.yaml xx"'
```

On the other hand, you can create a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#install) on your local machine.

Since you can deploy successfully locally, the self-hosted agent should be able to access Private AKS cluster directly using helm task.